# Cloudflare + Heroku with custom domain

Tags: heroku, dns, cloudflare

I have a Heroku app and connected Cloudflare. As I know, there is no way to remove a default Heroku domain (app.herokuapp.com), so I forward all requests with Host 'app.herokuapp.com' to 'mydomain.com'. But will Cloudflare secure me from attacks straight to a Heroku domain? If no, is it a way to remove default domain or hide it somehow?

Comment: what do you mean hide the default domain? when you forward all the traffic through cloudflare, it actually gets the response from the origin server and sends out its own http/https response + modifying the header, so it already hides the origin server. Now, even if you ping `mydomain.com` , you should see that it stops at cloudflare's network. It Doesnt even expose the origin server's info. those links [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36564586/how-to-prevent-exposing-origin-ip-address-on-cloudflare),[2](https://blog.cloudflare.com/ddos-prevention-protecting-the-origin/) might be useful

Comment: Also (sorry for the long comments !)  , for your second question i am not quite sure because if someone hits directly the Heroku domain, then only Heroku knows about it(i believe they have definitely some short of security), but your other option is to restrict the allowable IP's only to some that you like and Cloudflare's too. i dont know if its helpful , but Heroku offers something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136260/how-can-you-block-or-filter-ip-addresses-on-heroku) or [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/private-spaces)

Comment: For example, I have heroku app on `app.herokuapp.com` and connected domain `mydomain.com` with Cloudflare. If I go straight to `app.herokuapp.com`, I don't pass through Cloudflare's filters. Let's imagine, that there is DDoS attack on `mydomain.com`. Cloudflare will help me to protect. But now there is the attack straight on `app.herokuapp.com`. And since requests don't pass through Cloudflare, I could not protect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct at all points. I am giving you the easy ways for basic offloading of attacks. All methods are towards 301 redirect and/or packet forwarding.

> But will Cloudflare secure me from attacks straight to a Heroku
>   domain?

[Cloudflare has a service which they say CNAME flattening](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169056-CNAME-Flattening-RFC-compliant-support-for-CNAME-at-the-root). Few years back, it was dnsmadeeasy who *discovered* A Name. They are not RFC standardised. Many other DNS service has such things. Basic principle is easy. If app URL is `my-ugly-url.herokuapp.com` & your custom domain is `my-custom.com` then with  which you can set :

```
 | my-custom.com |
 @ my-ugly-url.herokuapp.com ( ANAME or ALIAS )
 app.my-custom.com CNAME my-ugly-url.herokuapp.com
 www.my-custom.com CNAME my-ugly-url.herokuapp.com
```

Then do 301 redirection at application's web server config, `app.my-custom.com` will redirect to `my-ugly-url.herokuapp.com`. Requests toward `my-ugly-url.herokuapp.com` will be forwarded to `my-custom.com` by dnsmadeeasy. There are probably more such DNS services now. Yes, chance of running attack over both domain in parallel is remaining. But also `my-ugly-url.herokuapp.com` get exposed on DNS record.

> If no, is it a way to remove default domain or hide it somehow?

Officially 301 redirection, packet forwarding is also possible. There are ways to have dedicated IP and forward TCP packets. They have 3 types of add-ons --

1. [/addons/proximo](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/proximo).
2. [/addons/fixie](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/fixie).
3. [/addons/quotaguardstatic](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/quotaguardstatic).

They are not always easy at application level but probably safer than having such naked subdomain open to all. [PaaS is facing increasing DDoS now](http://www.v3.co.uk/v3-uk/news/2356828/ddos-attackers-turn-attention-to-saas-and-paas-systems-akamai-reports). That is different matter.